# Fetched DateTime from MySQL DB increased by 3 hours [Spring]

Tags: mysql, spring, timezone, converters, localdatetime

when I fetch a `DateTime` from `MySQL` database using Spring, the received DateTime is `increased by 3 hours`.

What is the reason for that and how to solve this issue? I want the same date and time as it is in db.

**In model:**

```
@Column 
private LocalDateTime dateAndTime;
```

**Converters:**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {
    
    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime locDateTime) {
        return (locDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(locDateTime));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
        return (sqlTimestamp == null ? null : sqlTimestamp.toLocalDateTime());
    }
}
```

**In MySQL:**

left => column name,  right => datatype in mysql
[image]

the time is changed by 3 hours when received the data from DB...

**EDIT:**
I recognized that also when I save a `datetime` to the database the passed time is `decreased by 3 hours` and then saved in db... very strange.

**I checked time zone infos:**

- the column says timezone: `+ 0300`
- I have set up `Spring` to set timezone at startup to `GMT+3`

When I change the timezone in Spring to `GMT+0` then the `same time as in DB is returned`...but when I save a dateTime to the db is is `decreased by 3 hours`...very strange.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your `date_and_time`  column is already stored in EEST or some other UTC+3 timezone. So, `.toLocalDateTime()` pushes it forward another three hours.

Comment: No when I get the data and before tranforming it with .toLocalDateTime() it is already the wrong time... so I just get the changed time form db...I don´t know why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue...

in my datasource I had

```
...?&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useUnicode=yes&character_set_server=utf8mb4
```

see the `serverTimezone=UTC` ... just removed it and it works...